# Как дублировать строку в Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

**В Edit1 есть текст:**

```
 Сегодня 19.07.2020
```

Нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку эта строка **дублировалась 5 раз в memo1**. На выходе получим результат в memo1:

```
Сегодня 19.07.2020
Сегодня 19.07.2020
Сегодня 19.07.2020
Сегодня 19.07.2020
Сегодня 19.07.2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

полагаю это у вас первые шаги в освоении delphi, итак:

берёте значение из edit

```
S:=Edit1.Text;
```

и присваиваете его memo

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
```

делаете это в цикле 5 (или сколько вам нужно раз)

[мануал по компоненту edit](http://www.delphi-manual.ru/edit.php)

[мануал по компоненту memo](http://www.delphi-manual.ru/memo.php)

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решал используя цикл for i := 0.